# Side bar backgrounds not working

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting the background images to flow to the bottom of the site within my sidebars. What am I doing wrong? Also the content in the center of the page has decided to bunch up and I'm not sure how to fix that either...

How do I get it all to be an even three column layout?

https://jsfiddle.net/ofusmgbn/

Here is the css and html

```
h1{
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Peralta;
    color: white;
    height: 75px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 150px;}

h2{
    font-family: Peralta;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 0;}

p{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
     padding-bottom: 4em;
    height: 80px;}

img{
    float: left;

    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;}



ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;}

*{
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar1{
    float: left;
    width: 265px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
   background: url(sidebar1background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;

}

.main{

    float: left;
    width: 60%;
     padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    background-color: #d4ff80;
}

.sidebar2{
    float: right;
    width: 265px;
    padding-right: 30px;
     padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    background: url(sidebar2background.jpg)right top;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;


}





#footer{
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>SylviaGunter WEB-210 Project 6</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Peralta' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gochi+Hand|Peralta' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href=01%20-%20Large%20CSS.css>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="02 - Medium CSS">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="03 - Small CSS">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="04 - Print CSS">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="05 - IE"> 

</head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">


    <div id="masthead">
        <h1>Best TV Ever</h1>
            </div>

[insert menu toggle here]
[insert menu checkbox here]


<ul>
    <li><a href="#">50s</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">60s</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">70s</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">80s</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">90s</a></li>
    </ul>


<aside class="sidebar1">

   Best Prime Time Shows
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Alice</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">All In The Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Barney Miller</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Beverly Hillbillies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bewitched</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Bob Newhart Show</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Brady Bunch</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gilligan's Island</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Good Times</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Love Boat</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mary Tyler Moore</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">M*A*S*H</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Maude</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One Day At A Time</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Petticoat Junction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Soap</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Taxi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What's Happening</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Welcome Back Kotter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WKRP In Cincinatti</a></li>
</ul>

            </aside>


<article class="main">

<h2>The Genius of Krofft</h2>

<h3>H.R. Pufnstuff</h3>

<p> <img src="hrpufnstuff.jpg" alt="hrpufnstuff" height="150" width="200">H.R. Pufnstuf centered on a shipwrecked boy named Jimmy. He and his friend, a talking flute named Freddy, take a ride on a mysterious boat, which promised adventures across the sea, to Living Island. The Mayor of Living Island was a friendly and helpful dragon named H.R. Pufnstuf. The boat was actually owned and controlled by a wicked witch named Wilhelmina W. Witchiepoo who rode on a broomstick-like vehicle called the Vroom Broom. She used the boat to lure Jimmy and Freddy to her castle on Living Island, where she was going to take Jimmy prisoner and steal Freddy. But Pufnstuf found out about her plot and was able to rescue Jimmy when he leaped out of the enchanted boat with Freddy and swam ashore.</p>

<h3>Lidsville</h3>


<p><img src="lidsville.jpg" alt="lidsville" height="150" width="200">
The show involved a teenage boy named Mark who fell into the hat of Merlo the Magician and arrived in Lidsville, a land of living hats. The hats on the show are depicted as having the same characteristics as the humans who would normally wear them.</p>

<h3>The Bugaloos</h3>


<p><img src="bugaloos.jpg" alt="bugaloos" height="150" width="200">The Bugaloos featured a musical group composed of four British-accented teenagers, who lived in fictional Tranquility Forest. They wore insect-themed outfits with antennae and wings which allowed them to fly. They were constantly beset by the evil machinations of Benita Bizarre, played by comedienne Martha Raye.</p>

<h3>Land of the Lost</h3>


<p><img src="landlost.jpg" alt="landlost" height="150" width="200">Land of the Lost details the adventures of the Marshall family (father Rick and his teenage children Will and Holly) who are trapped in an alternate universe inhabited by dinosaurs, a primate-type people called Pakuni, and aggressive humanoid/lizard creatures called Sleestak.</p>

<h3>Sigmund the Sea Monster</h3>


<p><img src="sigmund.jpg" alt="sigmund"  height="150" width="200">The show centered on two brothers, Johnny and Scott Stuart, who discover Sigmund, a friendly young sea monster who had been thrown out by his comically dysfunctional undersea family for refusing to frighten people. The boys hide Sigmund in their clubhouse.</p>

            </article>



   <aside class="sidebar2">
  Best Superhero Shows
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Batman (1966)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Bionic Woman (1976)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Electra Woman and Dyna Girl (1976)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Greatest American Hero (1981)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Incredible Hulk (1977)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Isis (1975)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shazam! (1974)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Six Million Dollar Man (1974)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wonder Woman (1976)</a></li>
</ul>
            </aside>




<div id="footer">
Stop watching TV and write some code!
            </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your sidebars is that they have no height so they're just stretching to fir the content inside. If you want them to be a certain height, you'll need to define it.

Also, your content is bunched because the height set for the `<p>` tags is not enough. Just remove that altogether and make the tags display:block.

Comment: Duh! Thank you (ha) I added a height and voila! Now... can you see what is causing the middle content to scrunch up like it's doing?

Comment: Yep, it's the height of the tags. It's set to a fixed 80, which isn't enough for the them and since the overflow isn't set as hidden, it just goes outside of the boundaries.

Comment: Okay... Dumb question... what tags? What is it I need to remove?

Comment: The paragraph tags. You've got a style for them -

'p{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
     padding-bottom: 4em;
    height: 80px;}'

You need to remove the height and add display:block;